# This module requires that the HttpApplication implements IContainerProviderAccessor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

Hi
I want to use Autofac in my asp.net mvc appliation and here is the code I have in global.asxc file :

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ....

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    }
```

but when I run the project, I see this error :

This module requires that the HttpApplication (Global Application Class) implements IContainerProviderAccessor

what is wrong ?

Comment: I think I found the answer my self! First I impelmeneted from IContainerProviderAccessor, then I initialized IContainerProvider _containerProvider, within Application_Start() as follows :

 _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());

and then initialized container in this way :

IContainer container = _containerProvider.ApplicationContainer;

seems that every thing work fine.

Comment: Hi- can you please note the Autofac and MVC versions you're using? This message should never appear in recent versions. You may need to remove entries from Web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal global.asax.cs setup for autofac for asp.net mvc3 could look like this: 
(RegisterRoutes is removed from the code). As opposed to previous versions of asp.net mvc (from http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration)

> the HttpApplication class no longer needs to implement the IContainerProviderAccessor interface as described in the ASP.NET Integration documentation. All code related to implementing the interface should be removed your Global.asax.cs file.

You will also need a reference to Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

namespace ApplicationX
{
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        private static IContainer _container;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the container.
        /// </summary>
        public IContainer Container
        {
            get { return _container; }
        }

        // RegisterRoutes and RegisterGlobalFilters removed ...

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the first resource is requested from the web server and the web application starts
        /// </summary>
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Register: create and configure the container
            _container = BootstrapContainer();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_container));

            // MVC Stuff
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the web application ends
        /// </summary>
        public void Application_End()
        {
            // Release: remember to dispose of your container when your application is about to shutdown to let it gracefully release all components and clean up after them
            _container.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bootstrapper is the place where you create and configure your container
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An Autofac container</returns>
        private IContainer BootstrapContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            // You can make property injection available to your MVC views by adding the ViewRegistrationSource to your ContainerBuilder before building the application container.
            builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());
            // An example of a module that registers the dependencies for a ServiceLayer of your application
            builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, do you know anything about orchard project ? To be honest, I want to develop a mvc application which is composed of modules, by using Autofac.

Comment: @persian-dev I've heard about it but haven't worked with it yet. I edited the above code sample to include the registration of a custom module. How to build a module is documented on [http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as the OP, but my solution was different.

From [here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration):

> **Remove Old Items**
>
> - **Remove IContainerProviderAccessor interface from Global.asax.** This implementation is no longer used by ASP.NET MVC integration.
> - **Remove references to the AutofacControllerFactory.** The new MVC integration uses the MVC DependencyResolver class for integration instead.
> - [**Remove ASP.NET Autofac HTTP module configurations.**](https://github.com/AGBrown/AutofacABContrib/commit/1dc367e84a77a25a7ebfe561664e3a411110a7d1) Previously there were some Autofac ContainerDisposal and PropertyInjection modules required in your web.config. These should be removed.

Comment: I only removed the old ASP.NET Autofac HTTP module configuration from the web.config file. That works for me :-D